# Unable to isolate the problem in decoding/decrypt

Tags: java

I'm encrypting a password using the following

```
BASE64Encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(password[]))
```

I'm decrypting as follows

```
cipher.doFinal(BASE64Decoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedPasswordString))
```

However decrypt works for few and doesn't return proper text for many inputs. Sometimes it returns the input value itself which is weird.

Any suggestions or comments?

Thanks

Comment: I did a homegrown password manager, I needed to keep the initialization vector along with the key and use both to decrypt.

Comment: I can share that code tomorrow

Comment: Of course, you need to be careful of character encoding too as you can get quite different byte arrays for the same string depending on that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I have removed some of the code specific to my usage of encryption, and just providing the general way to use this.

This is what I used encrypt and encode

```
Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
sr.nextBytes(ivBytes);
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
sr.nextBytes(keyBytes);



SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
//Character encoding can mess things up. like UTF-8 etc. This is what the other commentors are talking about
byte[] dataInBytes = "the String you want to encrypt".getBytes("UTF-8"); 
byte[] encryptedBytes = aesCipher.doFinal(dataInBytes);

String base64Encoded = enc.encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
```

Then to decrypt:

```
 IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        
 Cipher aesCipher;
 aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        
 aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
    
 encryptedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Encoded) 

 byte[] decryptedBytes = aesCipher.doFinal(encryptedString);
 
 String yourString = new String(decryptedBytes);
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long. Try this, I pulled this code from a larger program I had written and I was doing more, like writing keys to files and updating properties files in other projects, so I tried to pull the relevant code for you and may have missed something, let me know.